# Lvm showing in suspended mode

Tags: lvm

LVM is in a suspended mode, how can I activate it?

I tried:

```
$ sudo vgchange -ay vgname
$ sudo Vgexport 
$ sudo Vgimport
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: Can you show the output that's leading you to believe it's suspended?

Comment: Pls check output

Comment: root@oc3823124265 mapper]# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume --- 
  LV Path                /dev/vg_oc2752458464/lv_root 
  LV Name                lv_root 
  VG Name                vg_oc2752458464 
  LV UUID                D7GTX0-4AAc-dGBb-PTVx-l70s-myew-OBx9ix 
  LV Write Access        read/write 
  LV Creation host, time oc5622173161.ibm.com, -11-19 00:01:24 -0500 
  LV Status              suspended 
  # open                 0 
  LV Size                289.09 GiB 
  Current LE             9251 
  Segments               1 
  Allocation             inherit 
  Read ahead sectors     auto 
  - cur

Comment: Please add this new info to your Q by editing it, comments aren't meant for code.

Comment: [root@oc3823124265 mapper]# lvdisplay | grep -i status
  --- Logical volume ---
  
  LV Status              suspended
  # open                 0
  LV Size                289.09 GiB
  Current LE             9251
  Segments               1

Comment: Please update your Q with all this new info!

Comment: please check below, I was uploading that
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26419150/IMG_20141209_183946.JPG